# Indexing and searching a list of list inside a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Let say we have a list of lists like this:

```
lst = [[[[1,2]]],[[[2,3]]],[[[3,4]]]]
```

and then we make a panda data frame here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['col'])
print df
```

and returns

```
        col
0  [[1, 2]]
1  [[2, 3]]
2  [[3, 4]]
```

what I want is replacing `col` with `green` when the interior list includes `1` and `red` if not. I tried this:

```
df['col'] = np.where(1 in df['col'], 'green', 'red')
print df
```

but does not return correct answer!!!

```
     col
0  green
1  green
2  green
```

I think the problem is that each element of data frame is a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` method; Also you have a list of list of list, you can either use `str[0]` to extract the first element (of list type) out or you can extract it from `x` in `apply`:

```
df['col'].str[0].apply(lambda x: 'green' if 1 in x else 'red')

#0    green
#1      red
#2      red
#Name: col, dtype: object
```

Another option:

```
df['col'].apply(lambda x: 'green' if 1 in x[0] else 'red')

#0    green
#1      red
#2      red
#Name: col, dtype: object
```